# Can anyone point out possible areas to investigate as to find the possible cause for 25% CPU usage in a Java process?

Tags: java, jprofiler

I have an application which reads a `SQL ResultSet`, parses the schema, and writes it to a `Parquet` file. I'm having a consistently high CPU usage in the function which writes to the `Parquet` file. I'm not sure if this is normal.

I am using `Xmx=512m` as a CLI parameter in the run.

I've run JProfiler to profile the application and I came up with `resultSet.getValue()` and `parquetWriter.write()` as the hotspots for method invocation. I also noticed the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics` thread being on waiting for a long time.

When I ran `hPROF` it gave me `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0` as being a massive consumer of CPU time.

`fixedColNames`, `colTypes` and `colNames` are all Hashtables which are built when the `ResultSet` is pulled in from SQL. I did this to prevent multiple functional calls to `ResultSet.getMetadata()`.

All in all, I've not figured out what specifically is causing my application to use so much CPU.

I've attached the Profiler snapshot and the thread stack too.

[CPU Cores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfB1k.png) [Profiler Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VArFO.png) [Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR2pm.png)

Attached Thread Dumps:

```
   https://gist.github.com/skitiz/87c12af3fa2b3c31113365e8c4d8dc74
   https://gist.github.com/skitiz/152f4968694fa612636f92af8a6087cb
   https://gist.github.com/skitiz/dd7c1cea7d4a527c36ba24f6bf73ee87
   https://gist.github.com/skitiz/af37552dd3340611b46040dc98338818
   https://gist.github.com/skitiz/9806469affdd651b41ea2bce3393e604
```

```
    private String saveParquetFile(
          Schema schema, ResultSet resultset, String fileName, String offsetKey) throws Exception {
        Path outFile = new Path(config.getExtractFilePath() + fileName);
        String offsetValue = null;
        ParquetWriter<Object> parquetWriter =
            AvroParquetWriter.builder(outFile)
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                .build();

        GenericRecordBuilder genericRecordBuilder = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (resultset.next()) {
          for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {

              genericRecordBuilder.set(
                  fixedColNames.get(i), extractResult(colTypes.get(i), colNames.get(i), resultset, 1));
        }
          rowCount = rowCount + 1;
          //                System.out.println(count++);
          parquetWriter.write(genericRecordBuilder.build());
          if (offsetKey != null) {
            offsetValue = resultset.getString(offsetKey);
          }
        }
        parquetWriter.close();
        rawDataLakeLoaderLog.setRows(rowCount);
        return offsetValue;
      }

    private Object extractResult(int mapping, String columnName, ResultSet resultSet, int flag)
          throws SQLException {
        Object temp = null;

        switch (mapping) {
          case Types.BIT:
            if (flag == 1) {
              temp = resultSet.getBoolean(columnName);
              return resultSet.wasNull() ? null : temp;
            }
            return Schema.Type.BOOLEAN;
          case Types.TINYINT:
            if (flag == 1) {
              temp = resultSet.getShort(columnName);
              return resultSet.wasNull() ? null : temp;
            }
            return Schema.Type.INT;
          case Types.SMALLINT:
          case Types.INTEGER:
            if (flag == 1) {
              temp = resultSet.getInt(columnName);
              return resultSet.wasNull() ? null : temp;
            }
            return Schema.Type.INT;
          case Types.BIGINT:
            if (flag == 1) {
              temp = resultSet.getLong(columnName);
              return resultSet.wasNull() ? null : temp;
            }
            return Schema.Type.LONG;
          default:
            if (flag == 1) {
              temp = resultSet.getString(columnName);
              return resultSet.wasNull() ? null : temp;
            }
            return Schema.Type.STRING;
        }
      }
```

I expect the CPU usage to be near 5-10%? But its coming out to be 25%.

Comment: No one should write `catch (NullPointerException e)` for any reason, ever.  If you think a value might be null, check for null and skip execution of the statement if necessary.

Comment: @VGR Removing the `try-catch` block does not seem to affect CPU usage though.

Comment: please share several thread dumps when your application is running. without any profiling tools attached.

you can use kill -3 <pid> to do so.

Comment: @AlexeyVlasov I attached the thread dumps you requested.

Comment: Please include any relevant information in the question itself, not on external sites that you link to. Thanks!

Comment: Pardon the basic question, but does this just mean that you have one process using 100% of a single core on a 4 core system, so that total utilization is 25%? Are you not expecting it to be CPU bound?

Comment: Could you explain why you expect 5-10% CPU usage? That seems to be a rather arbitrary value. As long as your application is doing something, CPU usage will be as high as possible, because, well, that's what the CPU is for. 25% sounds like you have 4 cores and your application just makes full use of 1 core. Seems pretty normal to me.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Java splits workloads over different threads. I have not implemented multi-threading in the application. But even if it is running on one core, is it expected to use 100% of a single core? I was expecting lower usage.

Comment: As long as you don't have multiple threads, your code runs on one core, however your OS might switch between cores. It would still always be one core, though. As long as your CPU doesn't have to wait for something (like user input or reading/writing from/to a slow file/network stream/etc), it will be used as much as possible. Why would it not be? That would slow down your applications for absolutely no reason.

Comment: I've attached a screen cap of CPU usage over the 4 cores @MaxVollmer. Seems like all the cores are being used simultaneously. 

Regardless, even if only one core is being used is there any way I can optimize it to reduce usage? Or is that not an option?

Comment: "optimize it to reduce usage" I am sorry, but that makes no sense. You always use as much CPU as the system lets you have. That's what the CPU is for. You want it to compute your stuff, you don't want it to chill while your app is waiting. If anything, you'd want to optimize your code to use 100% of the CPU by introducing multithreading.

Comment: I am sorry. let me clarify. I'm looking to design this application to run on a scheduler with several jobs of this application running at the same time. I want to optimize this application so that the server which it runs off can work efficiently and a few instances of this doesn't hog up the entire CPU.

Comment: That is not your concern when writing an application, that's what the OS is for. It schedules which application gets how much CPU resources. You can run your application with a lower CPU priority. That tells the OS: "Hey if something else needs CPU, I can wait."

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification!